# How to reduce the tk.Listbox shown values and add scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add a scrollbar to a listbox in tkinter and also reduce the amount of values to 2 or 3 that are shown in the listbox.

My code at the moment shows the listbox with all the inserted values and without a scrollbar although I have created one according to some reads:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
// some more tkinter items
// using a grid of 4 columns and 9 rows
// the first one rows are simple tkinter objects
yScroll = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL) // vertical scrollbar for the list_prio
yScroll.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='ns')
 
list_prio = Listbox(root)
list_prio.insert(1, "low")
list_prio.insert(2, "low+")
list_prio.insert(3, "normal")
list_prio.insert(4, "normal+")
list_prio.insert(5, "high")
list_prio.insert(6, "high+")
list_prio.insert(7, "very-high")
list_prio.insert(8, "very-high+")
list_prio.select_set(3)
list_prio.grid(row=6, rowspan=9, column=1)
list_prio.config(yscrollcommand=yScroll.set, width=10)
yScroll.config(command=list_prio.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

The above code will show this result:
[image]

I can observe the upper and lower edge of the scrollbar under the text "Select amount" and under the slider on the right.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make to show only 3 choices in the listbox (although I have 8)?

I did some updates in my code:

```
...
yScroll = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
yScroll.grid(row=6, rowspan=9, column=1, sticky='ns')
 
list_prio = Listbox(root, height=6, width=19)
list_prio.insert(1, "low")
list_prio.insert(2, "low+")
list_prio.insert(3, "normal")
list_prio.insert(4, "normal+")
list_prio.insert(5, "high")
list_prio.insert(6, "high+")
list_prio.insert(7, "very-high")
list_prio.insert(8, "very-high+")
list_prio.select_set(3)
list_prio.grid(row=6, rowspan=9, column=1, sticky='nw')
list_prio.config(yscrollcommand=yScroll.set)
yScroll.config(command=list_prio.yview)
    
label_amount = Label(root, text="Select amount:")
label_amount.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='ne')
 
amount = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale(root, from_=1, to=8, variable=amount)
scale.grid(row=6, rowspan=4, column=1, sticky='ne')
```

Which gives the below result, but still not very satisfied, because now it is to close to the radiobuttons, see:
[image]

It is better then before but I would like to have this listbox + scrollbar (in column 1) with some more space between the radiobuttons (column 0).

Comment: Set `height=3` in `Listbox(...)` to show 3 items in the listbox.  It is obvious that you have put the `Scale` and the `Scrollbar` in the same cell.

Comment: When you create your `Radiobutton`s insert `anchor = 'w', width = 20, `.

Comment: It is not a good design to put several widgets in same cell.  Better use a frame to hold the widgets instead.